# Downloading blocks problem and I can't see my transfer from Coinbase

Tags: transactions, blockchain, mist, wallet-transfer

[image]Good afternoon to everyone!
I have a big problem. I've downloaded the ethereum wallet and I made a tranferency from coinbase to my adress. I can't see it in my wallet. I red in the answers that I must wait that the program downloads all the chain structure before I can see it in my wallet. 
The problem is that every time I open the program it starts to download and it never ends because it increases constantly..what can I do?
How can I have my money back?Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your balance on etherscan.io, that is up to date. It's true what everyone says, you need to have an up to date blockchain download to see the latest transactions and that can take hours-days depending on your SSD/HD.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can see the transition in my account from etherscan.io but I think I can't move money from there. It's stuck with 197 block left..suggestions?

Comment: Use myetherwallet.com